# How did they get $e^{-2n\pi}$ as the argument.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms

How did they get $e^{-2n\pi}$ ?

I found this question in the college course material. The answer was provided and it doesn't matches mine.

> Express $\pi^{i}$ in $A+iB$ form.

What I did:

Let $\pi^{i}$ =$m$

taking logarithm both sides

$ilog{\pi}=log(m)$

$e^{(i log{\pi})}=m$

From the demoivre's theorem we have :

$cos(log{\pi})+isin(log{\pi})=m$

Which is in the form of $A+iB$ but the answer in the solution manual is:

> $e^{-2n\pi}(cos(log{\pi})+isin(log{\pi}))$

Point out my fault, Kindly!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex exponentiation is defined as $$z^w=e^{w\log z}$$ where $\log z=\ln  |z|+i\arg z.$ So,

$$\pi^i=e^{i\log \pi}=e^{i(\ln \pi+i\arg \pi)}.$$ Now, $\arg \pi=2n\pi,$ depending on the branch you choose for the complex logarith. Thus

$$\pi^i=e^{i(\ln \pi+2n\pi i)}=e^{-2n\pi}e^{i\ln\pi}=e^{-2n\pi}(\cos(\ln \pi)+i\sin(\ln \pi)).$$

Obviously if you work with the principal value of the complex logarith (that is, the argument is in $(-\pi,\pi]$ then $n=0$ and you have $$\pi^i=\cos(\ln \pi)+i\sin(\ln \pi).$$

The problem with complex exponential is that it is not injective as in the real case (note that $e^{2n\pi i}=1$). For this reason the logarithm is a multivalued function (that is, you have to choose a branch to work with).